# Error: "Invalid root in registry key" with Shell.RegWrite

Tags: vbscript, registry

When running this code:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite "HKLM\Whatever\", "MyValue", "REG_SZ"
```

I have problems with `.RegWrite` only on Windows 8 where I get the error:

> "Invalid root in registry key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with so unhelpful error description I need to do some tests to find out that it was permission issue. However, elevate the script solve this. And to make this real answer I should post what I done, right?

```
Call ElevateUAC

' ---------------------------
' my duty task goes here...
' ---------------------------


Sub ElevateUAC
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") Then
        'Launch the script again as administrator
        With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
            WScript.Quit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```